# result of creation account in firebase is true but it's not added in firebase console

Tags: android

(Application Flow)
sign up -> create account in firebase authentication, sharedpreference.put(email & pw) for automatic login, save user info in database in firebase -> login -> mainActivity

before I released apk and proguard, it works well without any problem.
But after I had problems with proguard, I eliminate proguard rules and change minifyEnabled true to false in gradle.

Then I rebuild and run my app.

result of FirebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword is true.
and result of UserData upload is true.
also result of login is true.

After all success, I checked my firebase console.
But new auth data is not added.
And userdata is created but every information is null.
Sharedpreference is empty as well.

I checked my previous code when it works well. 
All codes are same.
And I searched all day long, but I haven't gotten any hint for handling it.

==FirebaseAuth Class ===

```
public void singUp(String userEmail, String userPwd) {

    firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(userEmail,userPwd)
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(AuthResult authResult) {
                   firebaseAuthListener.onSignUpComplete(true);
                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                   firebaseAuthListener.onSignUpComplete(false);
                   if(e instanceof FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException) {
                       signUpErrorListener.setErrorMessage("이미 사용 중인 이메일입니다. 다시 시도해주세요.");
                   }
                }
            });

}

public void login(final String userEmail, String userPwd){
    firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(userEmail,userPwd)
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(AuthResult authResult) {
                    firebaseLoginListener.onLoginComplete(true);
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            firebaseLoginListener.onLoginComplete(false);
        }
    });
}

public void userDataUpload(final UserData userData){
    firestore.collection("User")
            .add(userData).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentReference>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(DocumentReference documentReference) {
            firebaseAuthListener.onUserDataComplete(true);
            String recording_key = documentReference.getId();
            recordingKeyListener.onSaveRecordKey(recording_key);
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            firebaseAuthListener.onUserDataComplete(false);
        }
    });
}
```

==SignUp Class =====

```
    complete_btn.setOnClickListener(this);

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    int id = view.getId();
    switch (id){
        case R.id.complete_btn:
            boolean check_pw = checkPassword(userPassword_textInput,check_userpw_textInput);
            if(check_pw) {
                if(isSignUpSuccess) {
                    isComplete();
                }else{
                    onSignUpComplete(true);
                }
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(this, "비밀번호 일치 오류입니다. 다시 입력해주세요.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            break;
    }

}

private boolean checkPassword(TextInputLayout userPassword_textInput, TextInputLayout check_userpw_textInput) {

   return true when passwords are same / return false in the other case
}

private void isComplete() {
    userEmail = changeToString(userEmail_textInput);
    userPwd = changeToString(userPassword_textInput);
    userAge = changeToString(userAge_textInput);
    userName = changeToString(userName_textInput);


        singUp();
    }

}

private void singUp() {
    setUserData();
    firebaseAuthData.singUp(userEmail, userPwd);
}
private void setUserData(){
    userData.setUserName(userName);
    userData.setUserEmail(userEmail);
    userData.setUserAge(userAge);
    userData.setUserGender(userSex);
    userData.setUserJob(userJob);
}



@Override
public void onSignUpComplete(boolean isSuccess) {
    this.isSignUpSuccess = isSuccess;
    if(isSuccess){
        firebaseAuthData.userDataUpload(userData);
        SharedPreference sharedPreference = new SharedPreference();
        sharedPreference.put(this,"email",userEmail);
        sharedPreference.put(this,"pwd",userPwd);
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "회원가입에 실패하였습니다.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        LoadingProgress.dismissDialog();
    }
}

@Override
public void onUserDataComplete(boolean isSuccess) {
    LoadingProgress.dismissDialog();
    if(isSuccess){
        goNext(MainActivity.class);
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "회원가입 실패 ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

}

If the result of creation auth data is true, new account info should be added in my firebase console. At the same time, save user's email and pw in user's device using shared preference, plus created userdata with information that user input not null.

Comment: Please, read how to create a [complete and MINIMAL](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. We don't need and we don't want to read 300 lines of code. First you must isolate your problem and than ask here if you didn't find anything on the internet. SO must be your last resort.

Comment: I'm sorry, I edited.

Comment: I found where starts the problem!! because of onClick Listener code,  "isSignUpSuccess" initialize false at the first time, it changed true and it works well.if(isSignUpSuccess) {
                    isComplete();
                }else{
                    onSignUpComplete(true);
                }

Answer (score 0):

=====SignUp Class=======
(Global Variable)
//for checking created user account but not setting userData in Database

```
Boolean isSignUpSuccess = true;
complete_btn.setOnClickListener(this);

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
int id = view.getId();
switch (id){
    case R.id.complete_btn:
        boolean check_pw = checkPassword(userPassword_textInput,check_userpw_textInput);
        if(check_pw) {
            if(isSignUpSuccess) {
                isComplete();
            }else{
                onSignUpComplete(true);
            }
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "비밀번호 일치 오류입니다. 다시 입력해주세요.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        break;
}

}
```